# Set Firefox to ignore certificates for localhost

Tags: firefox, ssl-certificate

I have several (web) servers set up in various different locations I can SSH to, using port forwarding to work with them pointing my Firefox to https://localhost:443/application (I use `ssh user@server -L 443:localhost:443` to connect).
Each server was set up with a different self-signed certificate (generated during server setup) which doesn't matter to me - there needs to be no real security involved. However depending on which server I'm connected to, my Firefox will always display a security warning after connecting to a different server. Sharing one certificate for all servers is not an option. Using different ports for each is also no option. Using http is no option as well.

**Is there any way to tell Firefox to accept all certificates on localhost (and only on localhost!) without reconfirmation, even if they change?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No I don't think so.  localhost isn't treated any differently to any other hostname.  So you accept an exception for a specific circumstance:  hostname+certificate.

If the certificate changes for a domainname, the exception no longer applies, and so you'll get prompted.

What you might want to consider is adding different host names to your `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1               localhost server1 server2 server3 server4
```

Then for each of the forwarded hosts, you would use `https://server1` or `https://server2` etc.  These would still point to 127.0.0.1, but with a different hostname.

Then you could accept an exception for each one.

Comment: I had already tried the hostname workaround. It works, but it doesn't allow me to simply bookmark https://localhost/app which would be far more convenient. I had hoped Firefox had a "list of hostnames to ignore certificates for" somewhere.

Comment: @BennyInc I don't follow - how is https://localhost/app more convenient to bookmark than https://app or https://server1/app ?

Comment: I have several servers I run this app on - so I'd only have to use the one localhost/app for each one, deciding which to use by choosing which server I tunnel to. Using several bookmarks would double the effort again, as I need to ssh into the correct one anyway but then would also have to select the correct bookmark.

Comment: @BennyInc Aah, I see.  You could pull this off with something like apache + ProxyPass, but it goes against the security fundamentals for a browser, so I don't think it is possible.  Perhaps someone will happen along with a better answer.

Comment: As no one came up with a better answer for now, I've accepted yours. While it's not ideal for my situation, it might help others with similar issues.